# Spotify Webplayer: Select Element 'Play' Button w/ Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spotify

I've been trying to select the **Play** button on Spotify's webplayer through selenium for a series of tests, but have been unable to successfully target it. I've tried through **CSS Selector**:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#header .button-primary").click()
```

and **xpath**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class=\"button-primary\"]")
```

**This is my error call stack:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Spotify Dumbass.py", line
>   37, in test_spotify_dumbass
>       driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#header .button-primary").click()   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 396, in find_element_by_css_selector
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 684, in find_element
>       {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 195, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 170, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"#header .button-primary"}
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/Ne/NepmGbBUFwK7TxfPj5g0gE+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpSLKAhJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10299)
>       at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/Ne/NepmGbBUFwK7TxfPj5g0gE+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpSLKAhJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:603)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controlling through Javascript**

**Is there a JS SDK for the player? Can I send play/pause commands using Javascript?**

The Play button doesn’t have any observable events, nor does it listen for any. Playback can only be triggered by the user clicking the button.
We’re certainly looking at creating a JS SDK; it’s a bigger project and right now we’re focusing on quickly releasing APIs to open up the general Spotify ecosystem (catalogue, playlists, etc).
None of these requests are falling on deaf ears, and we’re working hard to bring out as much functionality as we can.

From Sptotify's Dev Page

Answer (score 2):

*The "play" button is inside an iframe*, switch to it before locating the element:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("app-player")
play = driver.find_element_by_id("play-pause")
play.click()
```

Comment: For some reason, my iframe objects are completely empty inside the WebDriver elements... However the innerHTML shows up just fine in the Firefox browser debugger. Any idea why?

Comment: @Connor please consider creating a new question with details and we'll take a look. (throw me a link here). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711187/empty-iframe-in-selenium-yet-filled-in-browser-python