# Empty iframe in Selenium yet filled in browser (python)

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to control Spotify's browser player. All of the controls are put inside iframe sections.

**Problem:** The iframes are EMPTY in the Selenium WebDriver object. Yet, the iframes are filled with the correct content in the ACTUAL browser.

**Code sample:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

import time

username = 'myusername'
base_url = 'https://play.spotify.com/user/spotifydiscover/playlist/76HML2OQXigkyKopqYkeng'

browser = None

def login():
    global browser
    password = input("Password: ")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(base_url)

    browser.find_element_by_id('has-account').click()

    browser.find_element_by_id('login-usr').clear()
    browser.find_element_by_id('login-usr').send_keys(username)

    browser.find_element_by_id('login-pass').clear()
    browser.find_element_by_id('login-pass').send_keys(password)
    browser.find_element_by_id('login-pass').submit()

def next_track():
    global browser
    wrapper = browser.find_element_by_id("section-collection")
    print(wrapper.get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf-8'))
    iframe = wrapper.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
    print(iframe.get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf-8'))
    sub = browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
    sub.find_element_by_id('next').click()

def test():
    login()
    time.sleep(14) # Adjusted until page is 100% fully loaded
    next_track()
    time.sleep(40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
iframe = wrapper.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

There are multiple `iframes` on the page and you are interested in the one with `app-player` id:

```
browser.switch_to_frame("app-player")
# now use browser.find_element_* to locate elements inside iframe
```

Also note that using `time.sleep` makes your automation code seriously fragile and usually slower than needed - instead use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the specific conditions to be met on a page.

Comment: Ahh thanks! Yeah I had tried a lot of things similar to that, but couldn't get it to work.